# loop through specific columns in table of excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop through an excel table and mark all rows with a colour where it finds an empty cell. That works.

But I want to specify now the columns where it should only search.
This is the actual code:

```
Sub Mark_Empty()

Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant


Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
Set myArray = myTable.DataBodyRange


For Each cell In myArray
    If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select a specific column rather than the entire table body with `Set myArray = myTable.ListColumns(2).Range`. Change the `2` to whichever column you need.

```
Sub Mark_Empty()

Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant


Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
Set myArray = myTable.ListColumns(2).Range


For Each cell In myArray
    If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Next cell

End Sub
```

**Edit**

I've went back to your original solution to iterate through each cell and then used a `Case` statement to check the column number. Your initial `IF` will only be executed if the column number matches those defined in the `Case`.

I don't claim it to be the best solution, but will do what you need.

```
Sub Mark_Empty()

Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant


Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
Set myArray = myTable.DataBodyRange


For Each cell In myArray
    Select Case cell.Column
        Case 2, 4, 5
            If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End Select

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Steven, and what should i do if i want to search in column 2,4 & 5?

Comment: Hi funny nobody writes a definition for the cell, Not needed? I get failure 'variable not defined'.

Answer (score 0):

The property [`DataBodyRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobject-databodyrange-property-excel) returns a `Range`, so you could take that `Range` and further restrict it as needed.
Note that you are assigning the return value to `myArray`, a `Variant`, so you should fix this prior to using what I propose.

Plus, a [`ListObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobject-object-excel) has other useful properties:

1. [ListColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobject-listcolumns-property-excel), which returns "a collection that represents all the columns in a ListObject object".
2. [Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobject-range-property-excel), which returns "a Range object that represents the range to which the specified list object".

This is all can be said without knowing more about how you want to restrict the `Range` to work with.